# How to retrieve bash shell return code in Windows Server with ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, windows-server-2008

We have a remote bash shell script on a Linux Server.
We have a local Windows Server 2008 box to use ssh to execute the remote shell script.
We cant seem to get the remote return code.

we tried

```
ssh remote "./remote_shell.sh test"   <-- returns 1
echo %errorlevel%
```

How do we do it right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's really [bash](/questions/tagged/bash); then the return code is `$?`

```
ssh remote "./remote_shell.sh test"
echo $?
```

Comment: Hi sputnick, thanks for responding. i tried your suggestion, it didnt work. It returns echo $! as $!

Comment: Opps, was a typo, see my edited POST. You have to run this in a bash shell, not cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh remote "./remote_shell.sh test; echo $?"
```

The `echo` command will print the exit status of the preceding command. It would be necessary to parse the number from the ssh output. You could make that a little easier by tagging the value:

```
ssh remote "./remote_shell.sh test; echo exit value was: $?"
```

Comment: Shouldn't SSH relay the exit code directly, so that `%errorlevel%` should work?